# What is the safest rechargeable battery?

Tags: batteries, safety

Lithium-ion batteries are commonly used today. What batteries (including those in the experimental stage) are safer (less likely to ignite due to damage, less harmful to health, and more stable) than LIB?

I'd like to know more than one.

Comment: There is sodium-ion and iron-air, you can read more about them on the Web.

Comment: What about calcium-ion batteries, potassium-ion batteries, and aluminum-air batteries?

Comment: This seems like a "list question" which is frowned upon, but there's always good old lead-acid (with massively different tradeoffs than lithium), as well as lithium iron phosphate (aka LiFePO4)

Comment: @user253751 He DID mention "less harmful to health".

Comment: Depends on how you define "safe". Lead-acid is very safe as in can handle electrical stress or faults very well - they don't explode. But battery acid is not "safe" if it gets in contact with humans. And obviously lead is a nasty substance for human health, which is otherwise banned from electronics nowadays. NiMH might be a good compromise - they don't explode but may catch fire during certain faults (polarity change).

Comment: @Lundin Last two UPSes I serviced each had an exploded SLA battery. I can imagine the event was far less energetic than li-ion but they were non the less ruptured violently.

Comment: @winny I think it takes some serious skill in order to make that happen. Like a direct short. I don't think any battery out there is foolproof.

Comment: @Lundin I was surprised too. Once perhaps but two in a row (both APC but different models with different sized individual batteries inside them) was almost basis to buy a lottery ticket. Nothing personal, I just took a stab at your _"they don't explode"_. I would say they _rarely_ explode. Both UPSes where happy after cleanup and battery replacement.

Comment: Wouldn't take much reading to highlight LFP and LTO as safer alternatives per the question body. But safest per title??? That's a different question and I doubt it'll get a useful answer.

Comment: @Lundin Don't smash the lead-acid battery into bits or eat it, and then it's safe for your health. The lead and the acid stay contained inside the battery and do not come out - to my knowledge. Especially if it is a sealed maintenance-free type (a little more expensive but worth it to avoid learning and doing maintenance)

Comment: @user253751 You might eventually eat it. One of the cornerstones of environmental science is: nothing you put in a product disappears through magic. All (harmful) substances have to go somewhere, chemical elements in particular. If you put lead in batteries then that lead will eventually end up somewhere. Car ends up at junkyard, junkyard leaks substances into groundwater, animals and plants drink that water, we eat the animals/plants. The further up in the food chain you are, the more such toxic substances you'll inherit from the organism below you in the food chain.

Comment: @Lundin there are special recycling plants for lead-acid batteries, which are very recyclable into new batteries.

Comment: @user253751 Alas, mankind is by no means anywhere remotely close to 100% recycling of _anything_, particularly not batteries. Anyway - this is off-topic - but my whole point is that no engineer should be so naive as to think that harmful substances in the products they design will only cause harm in case someone decides to lick directly on a PCB or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

Lithium iron phosphate batteries make a reasonable tradeoff between energy density and safety. Often they are packaged more resiliently I.e. in hard shells than lithium ion or lithium polymer ones, and are used in storage applications where a large bank of lithium ion batteries could be an excessive fire hazard, such as aboard ships and aircraft. They are also vastly more forgiving of charging and discharging mistakes.

Comment: to elaborate: you can see on youtube people stabbing lithium-polymer batteries and having them burst into huge fireballs (really dangerous)... you can also see people stabbing LiFePO4 batteries and a little smoke comes out (it's not *good* for the battery) but there's no flame, no explosion, and the battery still works afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Nickel Metal Hydride cells are pretty harmless.  They don't catch fire in any normal circumstances, and aren't particularly toxic or corrosive.

Nickel Cadmium is similar, but cadmium is toxic if released into the environment.